# how to track user existing session in tabs of browser

Tags: java, servlets, struts-1

my requirement is if user logged into website.then if he opens same website in new tab. 
then i have to check for an existing session. If one exists bypass the login screen and send them to the welcome screen.how can i do

Answer (score 0):

usually you want to prevent user from logging in when opening a second tab using concurrent session as for keeping track of session that depend on what you are using: example Spring security login which create the session on login (you can set its timeout too).